# pass two dimensional array from javascript to php but the size were reduced

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I want to pass a 2D array from javascript to PHP. but the result I get only part of the array.

I use `arr.length` to check the size is 75. 
and I use firefox developer tool to check the data posted is normal.
but  I use `sizeof($arr)` in PHP to check the size of 43.

I use apache as the server.
the content of array is string but not more than 10 character.

the following is the code I used.

javascript:

```
    myCol= 0 + $('#tabResult th').length; //75 
    myRow= 0 + $('#tabResult tr').length; //62

    var data = new Array(myRow);
    for(i = 0; i < myRow; i++){
        data[i] = new Array(75);
    }

    $.post('getReport1/getReport1ExportXls',{
        table: $('#getReport1List').html(),
        data: data,
        myCol: myCol,
        myRow: myRow
    },function(o){
        openXls();
    });
```

`

PHP:

```
$data=$_POST['data'];
```

Update 1:
In fact, the final array size(row x column) is closely to 1000. I already try to change php.ini `max_input_vars = 30000`
and run `httpd -k restart`
but no effect.

Comment: Do you get expected results with a small array, e.g. 75x45?

Comment: the final array size is smaller. 13x75 and 1x72. but if i set the column like 32, the row I get may be greater like 43x32 and 1 x 16. So now I doubt the problem is due to the setting of php.ini . but I already tried.

Comment: I'm asking whether you're getting 3x2 array in PHP, if you pass 3x2 array from JavaScript.

Comment: if I only get 3x2 arry. it is normal. now I found the final array size i got will be close to 1000 if I want to get an array (size >1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` variable is an array of `myRow` items:

```
var data = new Array(myRow);
```

And each item is an array of 75 elements:

```
data[i] = new Array(75);
```

So you're generating an array of size `myRow x 75`:

```
data = [
  item_1: [ ... 75 items ... ]
  ...
  item_myRow: [ ... 75 items ... ]
]
```

In PHP you should get the same:

```
count($_POST['data']); // "myRow"
count($_POST['data'][0]); // 75
```

According to your question, `myRow` equals to 43.

**Update**

I recommend to pack the array in JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data)
```

then decode it in PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

Then you'll be limited only to the [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and to the [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), of course.

Comment: Sorry, my question before have misleading. the table should be 62 x 75. but finally I received is like (13 X 75 and 1 X 72 )